# iPhone SDK: Dealloc vs. Release?

Tags: iphone

I am wondering what the difference is between release and dealloc? After reading, the memory management rules (See below)., I am thinking most of the time I will be using release.  However, I wanted to know what to do for properties.

@property(retain)....

I have been using dealloc but after reading this article I am not sure that is correct.

You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message. You are responsible for relinquishing ownership of objects you own using release or autorelease. Any other time you receive an object, you must not release it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should never call `dealloc` on anything other than `super`.

The only time you will be calling `dealloc` is in the `dealloc` method of a custom inherited object, and it will be `[super dealloc]`.

When the retain count of an object goes down to zero, `dealloc` will automatically be called for you, so in order to manage memory properly, you need to call `retain` and `release` when appropriate.

If this isn't clear to you or you'd like details about how memory is managed in Cocoa, you should read the [Memory Management Programing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 5):

You never call *dealloc* directly. It is invoked by the system when the *retainCount* of the object goes to 0. Every time you do a *retain*, the *retainCount* is incremented with 1. Every time you do a *release*, it gets decremented. This way, by balancing your *retains* and *releases*, you ensure than when the *retainCount* gets to 0, *dealloc* will be automatically called, and your object freed.

As Ben S noted, the only time and place you would call *dealloc* is in in the *dealloc* method of an inherited object.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@property(retain)` and then `@synthesize` to generate the property code, you do not need to do any manual memory management on the property.  The other answers are correct in that you shouldn't be using `dealloc` except in your own override of a parent class `dealloc`.